# Xcode10 error: "iPhone has denied the launch request"

Tags: xcode

Xcode10 error: "iPhone has denied the launch request"

Comment: Welcome! Please state the context in which you are having this problem, what you had tried to solve it and what is the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of things you can try to troubleshoot this problem.

- Make sure that iPhone is not locked, when Xcode launches the app.
- Reconnect your iPhone to your Mac.
- Restart Xcode
- Restart phone it may help
- Restart your machine as a last step to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue encountered because of invalid code signing. Make sure you are signing with developer, not with distribution.

If your certificates are not properly configured then you can create new build ID and check on sign automatically.

This will also solve your issue but best solution is to configure developer certificate.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a free Apple developer account, you can’t debug your apps on a device anymore. It is unknown if this is temporary or permanent, but if you want the app to launch without the error you have to go to Product -> Schemes -> Edit Scheme and uncheck the “debug” checkbox. You will not be able to debug the program but it will run.

Comment: "If you have a free Apple developer account, you can’t debug your apps anymore." This seems entirely unlikely. Do you have a reputable source for this claim?

Comment: This is very unlikely. You can debug your apps using free apple developer account. However, there is a limit on apps you can install on a physical device

Comment: You can install 7 application on your device even if you are having the free developer account, all you have to do is to check the singInAutomatically box with unique bundle ID.